# Cypress wont read .feature fle

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Iḿ using Cypress and Cucumber I installed all dependences propelly. However, Cypress shows this error while I:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzVBN.png)

cypress.config.js :

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");


const createBundler = require ("@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor")
const { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } = require ("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor")
const { createEsbuildPlugin } = require ("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild")

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://automationpratice.com.br/',
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",

    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

      on(
        "file:preprocessor",
        createBundler({
          plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
        })
      );

      // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
      return config;

      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});
```

Login.feature

```
Feature: Login
    Eu como cliente 
    Quero fazer login na aplicação
    Para fazer um pedido de compra

    Scenario: Login com campo e-mail vazio
        Given I am on login screen
        When I click on login
        Then I see the message "E-mail inválido"
```

login_steps.js

```
<reference types="cypress" />

import "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor"

import {Given, When, Then} from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor"
import home_page from "../pages/home_page.js"

Given("I am on login screen", () => {
    home_page.accessLogin()
})

When("I click on login", () => {

})

Then("I see the message {string}", (message) => {

})
```

home_page.js

```
<reference types="cypress" />

export default {
    accessLogin(){
        cy.visit('/')
            .get('#top_header')

            cy.get('.fa-user')
                .click()
    }
}
```

When I open cypress and try the .feature file it display:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqf2Q.png)

Comment: Can you share the package.json & what command you are using to run the tests?